# The type of B is displayed as A when `type B = A` is used. Why is it displayed as `any` when `type B = A | A` is used instead?

Tags: typescript, types

```
import { A } from "https://example.com/type.d.ts";
type B = A | A
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgQTgXzgMyhEcBEAFjDGAM4BcA9FQKYAeAhuADa0B0AxrlTAJ5gOAE3Ywy+ANwAofoLgAhOAF4UcAD4ogA)

If you hover on `B` in both TS Playground and VS Code, it will display it as `A` in the case `type B = A` and `any` in the case `type B = A | A`. Regardless of whether A is known or not, I expect they should be consistent. Why is that not the case?

Comment: `import { A } from "https://example.com/type.d.ts";` is not a valid import and not local either so the type of A becomes `any` as the typescript compiler can't infer any type

Comment: If TS doesn't know what `A` is, then `A` and `any` are equivalent... or rather, there's a compiler error, so TS falls back to `any` when evaluating `A`. So `type B` is `A`, and it's also `any`. Those are the same exact type. Why would it have to be one "instead of" the other? Is there some assumption you're making about how types work or how they are displayed that you could [edit] to articulate more clearly?

Comment: @jcalz In contrast, `B` is `A` when `type B = A`.

Comment: That doesn't explain much to me. You seem to have an unstated assumption that there's something special about how types are *displayed*, but you're not using the word "display" or "intellisense" or "quickinfo" anywhere so maybe I'm confused about what you're saying.  Imagine you were asking why a reference you expected to be to "Samuel Clemens" was actually to "Mark Twain". They're two different names for the same thing.

Comment: @jcalz I see. Thanks for being patience with me. Though I think that if I have an assumption that I don't even know, then I need someone to help me uncover it. Anyway, if you hover on `B` in both TS Playground and VS Code, it will display it as `A` in the case `type B = A` and `any` in the case `type B = A | A`. Regardless of whether A is known or not, I expect they should be consistent

Comment: So you’re specifically just talking about how types are *displayed*. That’s essentially the prerogative of TS; it uses heuristics to determine how to display a type, meant to support a wide range of use cases but by necessity cannot always do what everyone wants (two people want different things for the same code). Two different pieces of code can have two different displayed types; I’m not sure why what metric you’d claim that what’s happening now isn’t “consistent”.  You expect `A | A` to be reduced in some way, but not exactly the way that TS does it? Why does it matter to you?

Comment: (See prev comment) I’m trying to figure out how to answer this question objectively; TS doesn’t document its exact rules for type display; it’s largely an implementation detail and can change; some rules are fairly stable but your example seems like an extreme edge case: what does TS do in the face of a compiler error, when you declare a type in an invalid way? Even if I could find this info out by walking through the compiler or linking GitHub issues, I don’t know if it would give any real insight. What would you consider an acceptable answer to this question, as written?

Comment: (see prev 2 comments). Okay, the authoritative (and presumably unsatisfying) answer is [this comment in ms/TS#54630](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54630#issuecomment-1589486333): "There are no specific guarantees on what happens when there is an error type in your program." If you write a bad type, it's not even clear what "consistent" or "correct" behavior would be. First you fix your import, then one can think about how types are displayed (but again, this might not do what you want). Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yes, I just need an explanation. That's a good answer. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [microsoft/TypeScript#54630](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54630), specifically [this comment by the TS team dev lead](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54630#issuecomment-1589486333):

> There are no specific guarantees on what happens when there is an error type in your program.

When you import something that can't be found, you get a compiler error:

```
import { A } from "https://example.com/type.d.ts"; // error!
// -------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Cannot find module 'https://example.com/type.d.ts' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

and any references to it are going to be shown as whatever TypeScript wants to show it as.  It will often tend to show up as [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any), [because](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54630#issuecomment-1589547019)

> The hover shows "any" for lack of a better thing to display. It could be differentiated, but these things tend to not stick around in programs very long.

That explains why you see `any` *sometimes*.

---

As for why it shows `A` instead of `any` when you change from

```
type B = A | A
//   ^? type B = any
```

to

```
type C = A;
//   ^? type C = A
```

there's no documented and stable rule by which such types are displayed.  Assuming that `A` is sometimes displayed as `any`, then it's really the compiler's prerogative to decide which one of those it wants to display. Even if `A` weren't an error, you'd still have such a dichotomy:

```
type D = { a: string };

type E = D;
//   ^? type E = { a: string; }

type F = D[];
//   ^? type F = D[];
```

There you have type `D`, which is clearly an [alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) for `{a: string}`. Some uses of `D` get reduced to `{a: string}`, while others stay as `D`.

These differences are only how the type gets *displayed* to the user, and shouldn't affect the actual *identities* of the types. There are no supported official mechanism by which a developer can just tell the compiler which form she would prefer to see when displaying a type. There are various open feature requests like [microsoft/TypeScript#28508](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28508), [microsoft/TypeScript#31940](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31940), and [microsoft/TypeScript#45954](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45954), which could possibly change that if they were implemented, but for now it's not part of the language. The compiler uses heuristics to determine which is the type to display; these heuristics perform well enough in a wide range of use cases, but it is necessarily the case that they cannot meet everyone's needs simultaneously. For every person who wants `D` to be displayed as `{a: string}`, there is an equal and opposite person who wants it do be displayed as `D`, and they both have very important reasons for it to be that way, and both think their way would make things "consistent".  More developer control would be nice,  but without that, you just get what you get.

So: I can't easily say for certain why you see `any` for `A | A` but `A` for `A`, without stepping through the TypeScript compiler code and maybe finding pull requests that document the parts responsible. But even if I did that, it wouldn't be particularly enlightening, and it could easily change in a future version of TypeScript.  As long as two types are identical, in some sense it's completely up to the compiler to decide which one to show and when.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgQTgXzgMyhEcBEAFjDGAM4BcA9FQKYAeAhuADa0B0AxrlTAJ5gOAE3Ywy+ANxwacWlBxQAhACgZAWg2atmgHxwAfoaPGTps0dVU4AYUYA7OxHiZgdoXBAQhAVzZwA5MSklDQMzGBsXDz8guwiYv5w0HDAYnDc8rRkkG6uAOZwMbRwQrScLIxQjDDAEHZk7MrKRXAAQnAAvChwAD4olnCDAHoA-M0CxdadKBIDw2PjgnAAItNIjBRwZDBQ+eizLQCi08uzMvOLxQBiJwDaALpnVhdAA)